# Toggle element with checkbox with certain attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So I have this list of child pages sorted by title. And I am using custom fields wordpress plugin.

This is one of the lines in content of that li element

```
<p>City: <?php the_field('city',$page->ID); ?></p>
```

I want to make checkbox (somewhere on the page) so that if you uncheck that check box, element with, lets say city=NewYork, will disappear.

Code so far:

```
                        <input type="checkbox" class="newyork" name="beograd" checked>Chicago<br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="cicago" name="Chicago" checked>Pancevo<br>

                        <?php
                    $mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'meta_value' => '', 'sort_column' => 'city', 'sort_order' => 'asc' ) );

                    foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
                        $content = $page->post_content;
                        if ( ! $content ) 

                        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
                    ?>

                        <li class="clan">
                            <a class="noselect"><?php the_field('naziv',$page->ID); ?></a>

                            <div class="clan_content">
                                    <div class="podaci">

                                        <p>City: <?php the_field('city',$page->ID); ?></p>

                            </div>
                        </li>



                    <?php
                    }   
                ?>
```

**SUCCESS**

added `<li class="clan" title="<?php the_field('city',$page->ID); ?>">`

And then

```
$(function () {
                                  $('#newyork').change(function () {            
                                     $(".clan_content").stop().slideUp();                                     
                                     $("[title=NewYork]").toggle(this.checked);
                                  }).change(); 
                                });
```

Comment: show rendered html and the js you have tried so far.

Comment: @guradio Done. So, I want to hide every Li element with class="clan" when that element contains city = "New York" for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to jQuery something like this may work.  And it could be expanded to have the key and value set as attributes, so it isn't so hard coded.

```js
$(function(){
  // Listen for a filter click
  $('.stateFilter').click(function(){
    var ref = $(this), // The input
        state = ref.attr('state'), // The state I want to filter
        states = $('div.state[state='+state+']'); // What I should filter
    if (ref.is(':checked')) { // If checked, show, otherwise hide
      states.show();
    } else {
      states.hide();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="state" state="newYork">New York</div>
<div class="state" state="newYork">Pittsford</div>
<div class="state" state="newYork">Rye</div>
<div class="state" state="alabama">Birmingham</div>
<div class="state" state="alabama">Montgomery</div>
<div class="state" state="alabama">Auburn</div>

<hr/>

<!-- Create Filters for Each Key you want to filter on, here I added a state attribute to the input tags, which I can reference from jQuery -->

<p>
<input class="stateFilter" type="checkbox" state="newYork" label="check_newYork" checked/> <label for="check_newYork">Show <b>New York</b> Cities</label>
</p>
<p>
<input class="stateFilter" type="checkbox" state="alabama" label="check_alabama" checked/> <label for="check_alabama">Show <b>Alabama</b> Cities</label>
</p>
```

I took another stab with the latest info.  I converted the php into what the html should be, but i'm not sure if it achieves everything.  And I needed to add more attributes to simplify everything.

```js
$(function(){
  // Auto-Generate checkboxes and sort them, via jQuery magic
 var cities = [], cityMap = {}, i, city, clan_filters = $('#clan_filters'), p, items;
 // Collect cities, eliminate duplicates
 $('#clans li.clan').each(function(){
  var ref = $(this), city = ref.attr('city');
  // Make sure we don't duplicate the cities by using maps
  if (!cityMap[city]) { // If I haven't see this city, update the make and list
   cityMap[city] = true;
   cities.push(city);
  }
 });
  // Clean out the map, not needed
 cityMap = undefined;
  // Build the checkboxes
 for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
  city = cities[i];
  p = $('<p></p>').appendTo(clan_filters);
  p.append($('<input type="checkbox" class="clan_filter" checked/>').attr('value', city));
  p.append($('<span></span>').text(city));
 }
  // Get this reference to save time
 items = $('p', clan_filters);
 // Sort the chjeckboxes
 items.sort(function(a,b){
        var keyA = $(a).text();
        var keyB = $(b).text();

        if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
        if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
        return 0;
 });
 // Re-attached the sorted items, but this time in order
 $.each(items, function(i, li){
        clan_filters.append($(li));
 });
 // Event Handlers
 $('input.clan_filter[type=checkbox]', clan_filters).change(function(){
  var ref = $(this), // The input
        checked = ref.prop('checked'), // Am i checked?
        city = ref.val(); // What city is this for?
  $('#clans li.clan[city='+city+']').toggle(checked);    
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="clan_filters">

</div>

<!-- Commenting out code since this needs to be html
<ul id="clans">
<?php
 $mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'meta_value' => '', 'sort_column' => 'city', 'sort_order' => 'asc' ) );

 foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
  $content = $page->post_content;
  if ( ! $content ) $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
?>
  <li class="clan" city="<?php the_field('city',$page->ID); ?>">
   <a class="noselect"><?php the_field('naziv',$page->ID); ?></a>
   <div class="clan_content">
     <div class="podaci">
      <p>City: <?php the_field('city',$page->ID); ?></p>
     </div>
   </div>
  </li>
<?php
 }   
?>
</ul>
-->

<!-- This is what I think the output should look like -->
<ul id="clans">

 <li class="clan" city="Pancevo">
  <a class="noselect">What is this? B</a>
  <div class="clan_content">
   <div class="podaci">
    <p>City: Pancevo</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </li>

 <li class="clan" city="Chicago">
  <a class="noselect">What is this? A</a>
  <div class="clan_content">
   <div class="podaci">
    <p>City: Chicago</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </li>
 
<ul>
```

Comment: I updated the post with original code so far, can you take a look please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with jQuery

```
$('checkbox').click(function () {
    if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('[city="New York"]').hide();
    }
});
```